# Exception on Serialization when making Active Directory calls

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, active-directory

I have code in my Facade layer to make calls to active directory

```
activeDirectoryUserCache = new MyFacade()
  .GetActiveDirectorySearchResults(MyEnum.MemberCategory.User);
```

This call works fine in my local machine. But when the same is deployed to DEV server, it throws the following exception.

> {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream
>   is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are:
>   53-79-73-74-65-6D-2E-49-4F-2E-46-69-6C-65-4E-6F-74 ...
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerializationHeaderRecord.Read(_*BinaryParser
>   input)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.*_BinaryParser.ReadSerializationHeaderRecord()
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeBinaryResponseMessage(Stream
>   inputStream, IMethodCallMessage reqMsg, Boolean bStrictBinding)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Drive.Beagle.Server.BeagleFacade.GetActiveDirectorySearchResults(MemberCategory
>   memberType)    at
>   Drive.Beagle.Client.BeagleController.get_ActiveDirectoryUserCache() in
>   C:\Development\ MyProject\ClientCtrlr\MyController.cs:line 68}

As I understand the active directory call works with the Principal Objects and I believe they are not serializable by default and I cannot mark them as they are .net reserved objects. But what should I be doing in order to get rid of this issue?

I am using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;` namespace for AD Get users and groups calls.